# Convert string to double without parse or tryparse in C#

Tags: string, parsing, double

How can I convert a string to a double using a method that does not include parse or tryparse? I have the program for converting a string to a long, would it be the same for a double? I am a complete newbie.

Code snippets from OP comment below:

```
public static bool isLong(string s) { 
  bool n = true; 
  int a = 0; 
  s = s.Trim(); 
  for (a = 0; (a < s.Length); a = a + 1) { 
    n = n && ((s[a] >= '0') && (s[a] <= '9')); 
  } 
  return (n); 
} 

public static long toLong(string s) { 
  long ret = 0; 
  int a; 
  s = s.Trim(); 
  if (isLong(s)) { 
    for (a = 0; (a< s.Length); a = a + 1) { 
      ret = (ret * 10) + (s[i] - '0'); 
    } 
  } else { 
  } 
  return (ret); 
}
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you will get more help as you ask better questions. Open ended questions like this one are very hard (and time-consuming) to even try to answer. Please check out the page on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
One of the best ways to get help is to show us a short piece of code that is not working and ask for help on how to change it. Have you tried changing the code that does work for long to something similar that you think should work for float? And, if  it didn't work, what error message did you get?

Comment: public static bool isLong(string s)
        { bool n = true;
            int a = 0;
            s = s.Trim();
            for (a = 0; (a < s.Length); a = a + 1)
            {
                n = n && ((s[a] >= '0') && (s[a] <= '9'));
            }
            return (n);
        }
       This is the method I have for isLong. The next post will show the method for toLong. Thinking of how to change these for doubles.

Comment: public static long toLong(string s)
        {
            long ret = 0;
            int a;
            s = s.Trim();
            if (isLong(s))
            {
                for (a = 0; (a< s.Length); a = a + 1)
                {

                    ret = (ret * 10) + (s[i] - '0');

                }
            }
            else { }
            return (ret);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think I now understand the question. If so, the answer is yes, sort of.

long is an integer type, so processing one digit at a time is fairly straight forward.

double is a floating decimal type, so you have to figure out a way to deal with the decimal period in the middle.

Is this a class assignment or something where you absolutely must write this code on your own? If not, please consider using the library functions that already exist for this purpose, such as stod: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/